# Fully removing label from selection.insertcaption

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I have a script that takes information from a set of CSVs and creates tables with them. I've been adding a caption to each table by using

```
$Selection.InsertCaption(-2, " $owner - server information report", $null, $null, $true)
```

Which gives a caption that says "1 $owner - server information report". The $true makes it so the caption label, "table", does not show.

I'm wondering if there is any way to remove the number that is left over from the label. I've tried using $doc.content.text then replacing "table 1" but that just deletes the tables and leaves the text that was inside of them.

Edit: It seems the 1 left over isn't actually a 1. Right clicking it and selecting "Toggle field codes" changes it to "{ SEQ Table * ARABIC }"

Comment: Found the solution to my problem.

    $selection.start = 0
    $selection.end = 0
    $selection.delete(1,8)

1 means you're deleting characters, and 8 means you want to delete the next 8 characters

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem.

```
$selection.start = 0
$selection.end = 0
$selection.delete(1,8)
```

1 means you're deleting characters, and 8 means you want to delete the next 8 characters. Change start and end based on where your caption is on the document.